# Index out of Bounds issue in Java

Tags: java, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception, bounds, out

So I have this code for an assignment in university, it's giving me an index out of bounds for some reason I don't know, the purpose of this method is to invert routeLocation (which is an ArrayList) and then takes the inverted ArrayList & adds it to the String fullRoute with a comma between every element in the ArrayList.

```
public String getFullRoute() {
    int x = this.getRouteLocations().size();
    int i = 0;
    fullRoute = this.getRouteLocations().get(0) + ",";
    ArrayList<FunRide> temp = new ArrayList<FunRide>();
    while (x > 0) {
        temp.add(this.getRouteLocations().get(x));
        x--;
    }
    int w = temp.size();
    while (i < w) {
        fullRoute = fullRoute + "," + temp.get(i);
        i++;
    }
    return fullRoute;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int x = this.getRouteLocations().size();
```

should be

```
int x = this.getRouteLocations().size()-1;
```

And you also need to change `while (x > 0) {` to `while (x >= 0) {`.

Currently in your first iteration you're trying to access the elements at the index equals to the size of the list. Since it's 0 base indexed, they goes from 0 to size - 1.

I.e for a list of two elements let's say `myList = List(5,15)` (so the size of the list is 2) you have:

```
index value
0       5
1      15
```

In your first iteration you're doing `myList.get(x);` which is equivalent to `myList.get(2);` as you initialized `x` with the size of your list.

Also note that you don't need to create a temporary list. A simple loop that going through the end to the front of the original list would suffice, so something like this:

```
public static String getFullRoute() {
    int x = routeLocation.size()-1;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(routeLocation.get(0)).append(',');
    while (x >= 0) {
        sb.append(',').append(routeLocation.get(x));
        x--;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you that got rid of the issue, but could you tell me why did this error occur? :)

Comment: @user3442961 What don't you understand in my explanation?

Comment: nothing got it all for some reason my browser didn't show to full reply at first, thanks a lot